# Open port for sending gmail centos 7

Tags: php, email, centos, centos7

I can send mail when I try on my localhost and i receive it correctly, but when upload my project to a Cent OS 7 server, i can not receive email anymore. I figure out that the port for sending email (587) may not open( i used n map to scan). Can i configure it myself to open the port 587 for sending mail or i have to do something else?

```
'gmail' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'username' => 'user@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'timeout' => 30,
        // 'tls'=> true,
        'transportsrt' => 'smtp',
    ],
```

Comment: http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html

Comment: i haven't turned on the firewall yet

Comment: In Cent Os it's turned on automatically.